# Selecting only checkboxes within the parent div

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-selectors

I am attempting to apply some jQuery to checkboxes but only within the nearest div.

I have a list of x dynamically created checkboxes - if all the checkboxes are blank then I want them all to show as checked.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
</div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('.limitall:checkbox:checked').length == 0){
    $('.limitall').prop('checked', true);
  }
  $(".limitall").change(function(){
    if ($('.limitall:checkbox:checked').length == 0){
      $('.limitall').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

This works fine as long as there is only one "set" of items with a class of limitall on the page - if there is more then this treats both groups as one set and this only works if all 10 are blank.

So if I have:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="3">3</label>
</div>
```

this treats this as a set of 6 rather than 2 sets of 3 - how can I ensure that this doesn't happen and that each set is treated independently?

The above HTML structure will always apply so the checkboxes are always inside a label which is inside a div with a class of col-lg-6 but the name of the input is dynamically set so I cannot use that

https://jsfiddle.net/3dgo3Laz/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  checkedBox($(".col-lg-6.Active"))
  $(".col-lg-6.Active  input:checkbox").on("change", function () {
    checkedBox($(this).parent().parent());
    });
});

function checkedBox(Element) {
  $.each(Element, function (index, value) {
  var hasCheked = false;
  if ($(value).find('input:checkbox').is(":checked"))
      hasCheked = true;
  if (!hasCheked)
     $(value).find(' input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
   });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="col-lg-6 Active">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" checked class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]"  class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 Active">
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions3[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions3[]" class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
        <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions3[]" checked class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really close! My only issue is this code seems to apply to any checkbox with the class checkbox-inline but there are some I do not want it to apply to. I tried changing the class in your code from .col-lg-6 to something else and then only have that class on the ones I want but it still applies to everything. Is it possible for this code to only apply to col-lg-6 with a specific additional class on the div?

Comment: The second series does not have "active" class and don't affected .

Answer (score 0):

You could give your `divs` and id or a special class and target the checkboxes within that `div`. For example:

```
<div class="col-lg-6" id="checkboxes-1">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions[]" class="perm limitall" value="3">3</label>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6" id="checkboxes-2">
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="1">1</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="2">2</label>
    <label class="checkbox-inline"><input type="checkbox" name="permissions2[]" class="perm2 limitall" value="3">3</label>
</div>
```

That way, you can change your selector to:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  if ($('#checkboxes-1 .limitall:checkbox:checked').length == 0){
    $('#checkboxes-1 .limitall').prop('checked', true);
  }
  $("#checkboxes-1 .limitall").change(function(){
    if ($('#checkboxes-1 .limitall:checkbox:checked').length == 0){
      $('#checkboxes-1 .limitall').prop('checked', true);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: he says: "The above HTML structure will always apply so the checkboxes are always inside a label which is inside a div with a class of col-lg-6 but the name of the input is dynamically set so I cannot use that". Also u can't use the same id in two different tags. It's not w3c compilant

Comment: the name of the input is dynamically set, maybe he can change the div's id.

Comment: Both div's have the same ID?

Comment: OK but even now doesn't that mean I need to have a jQuery code block for every html block?

Comment: No, you can do that dynamically (using the index from a forEach function) as the ID of the selector. I don't know exactly what you need, maybe you could clarify?

Comment: Regardless of how many HTML blocks there are they each need to be treated independently - they are dynamically added so I have no idea if there is 1 or 5 on a page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146910/discussion-between-bravozulu-and-bhttoan).

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over all `.col-lg-6` elements and set a unique id. You also would move your event handling logic inside a generic function.

```
$(".col-lg-6").each(function(idx) {
    var id = 'someidentifier' + idx
    $(this).attr('id', id);
    handleEvents(id);
});

var handleEvents = function(id) {

   $('#' + id + ' .limitall').change(function(){
      /*your logic*/
    }); 
}
```